# Java DAO implementation setObjects

Tags: java, dao

There is such problem.
[image]

I have some entity classes `Appartment`, `Landlord` etc. Now I'm creating `ApartmentDaoImpl`, that is DAO implementation for `Apartment`. Everything is clear with primitive types, I can get `landlordId`.

The question is - how to set `Landlord` field by his `id`?

This doesn't work because `getId()` method is non-static:

```
Apartment apartment = new Apartment(id);
            apartment.setRooms(rooms);
            apartment.setDescription(description);
            apartment.setFree(free);
            apartment.setPrice(price);
            apartment.setLastUpdatedPrice(lastUpdatedPrice);
            apartment.setLandlord(Landlord.getId());
```

Comment: Get a landlord-instance, for example `Landlord landlord = ...`, and then you can do `apartment.setLandlord(landlord.getId());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to decalre Landlord Object and set its properties, e.g.:

```
Landlord landlord = new Landlord();
landlord.setName("foo");
landlord.setEmail("foo@bar");
etc.
```

Alternatively, you can get it from DB, if the record already exists:

```
Landlord landlord = dataAccess.getLandlordByName("hereGoesTheName");
```

Of course, in the latter case, you need to implement a proper DataAccess class and access its method by `dataAccess` Object.

Only then you can assign it to the Apartment Entity:

```
apartment.setLandlord(landlord);
```

Aside from that, it seems to me that you don't really grasp basic concepts of OOP. Nothing's wrong with that, but the problem you are trying solve is quite an advanced one.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I need - to get Landlord from DB.
But if my `AppartmentDaoImpl` will implement `LandlordDao` as well then I will also need to realize all of its methods. The same situation with `AddressDao`.
How to avoid that?

Comment: To me it's fairly reasonable to have a DataAccess implementation for most Entities, at least those crucial ones. Just make LandlordDAO class implement all methods allowing you to acces Landlord by Name, by Id, fetch all his/her Apartments, etc.

Comment: I already have DAOs for all my Entities.
This one should work right:
`int landlordId = rs.getInt("landlord_id");
 LandlordDaoImpl landlordDao = new LandlordDaoImpl(conn);
 Landlord landlord = landlordDao.readById(landlordId);
 apartment.setLandlord(landlord);`